# Change value of array element which is being referenced in a .each loop?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How do I get the following to happen: I want to change the value of an array element which is being referenced between pipe characters in a `.each` loop.

Here is an example of what I want to do, but is not currently working:

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x.each { |element|
   if(element == "hello") {
       element = "hi" # change "hello" to "hi"
   }
}
puts x # output: [hi there world]
```

It's hard to look up something so general.

Comment: There's a series of blog posts called [Enumerating enumerable](http://www.globalnerdy.com/tag/enumerating-enumerable/) that you may find useful.

Answer (score 39):

You can get the result you want using `collect!` or `map!` to modify the array in-place:

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x.collect! { |element|
  (element == "hello") ? "hi" : element
}
puts x
```

At each iteration, the element is replaced into the array by the value returned by the block.

Comment: In case anybody wonders. Aside from the name, `collect!` and `map!` are identical functions. See [Difference between map and collect in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254732).

Answer (score 36):

The `each` method never changes the object it works on.

You should use `map!` method instead:

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x.map! { |element|
   if(element == "hello")
       "hi" # change "hello" to "hi"
   else
       element
   end
}
puts x # output: [hi there world]
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `"hi"` to `element`? `element` is a block-local variable that goes immediately out of scope anyway. This simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 10):

Map is probably the best way, but you can change the string in-place too.

```
> a = "hello"
> puts a
=> hello

> a.replace("hi")
> puts a
=> hi
```

changes the internal value of the string. For example, your code could become :

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x.each { |e| if (e == "hello"); e.replace("hi") end; }
```

but this is much nicer :

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x.map! { |e| e == "hello" ? "hi" : e }
```

Comment: +1, dead handy way of doing things. While not specifically answering this question, you can replace via index too, i.e. a[0].replace('HI'). That's what I was looking for, and your answer got me there. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x[index] = "hi" if index = x.index("hello")
x[index] = "hi" if index
```

or

```
x = %w(hello there world)
index = x.index("hello") and x[index] = "hi"
```

But one notice: it will replace only first match. Otherwise use `map!` as @SirDarlus [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646710/ruby-change-value-of-array-element-which-is-being-referenced-in-a-each-loop/5646754#5646754)

Also you can use `each_with_index`

```
x.each_with_index do |element, index|
  x[index] = "hi" if element == "hello" # or x[index].replace("hi") if element == "hello"
end
```

But I still prefer using `map!` :)

Comment: I like the last one using `each_with_index` because it does not do extra thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way has less lines of code:

```
  x = %w(hello there world)
  x = x.join(",").gsub("hello","hi").split(",")
  puts x
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply:

```
x = %w(hello there world).map! { |e| e == "hello" ? "hi" : e }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple you can do the same -

```
x = %w(hello there world)
x = x.collect { |element|
 if element == "hello"
   element = "hi" # change "hello" to "hi"
 end
 element
}
puts x # output: [hi there world]
```