# Why doesn't 'each' iterator go through the whole array?

Tags: ruby, each

I tried to execute this code in Ruby:

```
array=[1,2,3,4,5]
array.each do |x|
  puts array.length
  puts "Downloading #{array.length} files"
  array.pop
end
```

I got:

```
5
Downloading 5 files
4
Downloading 4 files
3
Downloading 3 files
```

I don't understand why I'm getting only three iterations. What am I doing wrong (apart from not using a `while` loop)?

Comment: Do not mutate enumerables while iterating. This question was a dozillion times answered here.

Comment: Relevant question: [Change value of array element which is being referenced in a .each loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5646710/2620080)

Comment: If you provide an explanation about what you want, we might be able to provide you a different solution.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner. I know I can do this iteration differently, but I didn't understand why I was getting only iterations till array consisted of 3 elements. Thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened before was this:

1. `array.length` is 5
2. x = 1 is being processed
3. array.shift (`array.length` is 4)
4. Array length = 4
5. x = 2 is being processed
6. array.shift (`array.length` is 3)
7. x = 3 is being processed
8. array.shift (`array.length` is 2)

Now there are no more array items to iterate through, because the last 3 items (3,4,5) are popped.

A better way to do is to reverse the array and shift it

```
array=[1,2,3,4,5]

array.reverse.each do |x|
  puts array.length
  puts "Downloading #{array.length} files"
  array.shift
end
```

What happens now is, the array now is `[5,4,3,2,1]`.
Each loop it processes the first item in the array, puts the array length, and then removes the value using `shift`.

Comment: Thank you! That's kind of help I was hoping to get!

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you iterate from begin of `array` it means:

```
1 step: puts array[0] and you delete array[4] element(array => [1, 2, 3, 4])
2 step: puts array[1] and delete array[3] element(array => [1, 2, 3])
```

If you want to delete each element after returned it, you can do it in many variants, some of it:

```
array.reverse.each do |x|
  puts "Downloading #{x} files"
  array.pop
end
```

or

```
array.size.times do
  puts "Downloading #{array.pop} files"
end
```

If you don't want to get empty `array` after this iteration, you can just:

```
array.reverse.each do |x|
  puts "Downloading #{x} files"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, `array.pop` is decreasing your array's length. In last line

```
3
Downloading 3 files
```

your array's length is 3 and your **each loop is already run 3 times**. that's why its not iterate next element. (Here, each loop iterate only 3 elements because your array's length is 3)