# Better ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I'm fairly new to ruby and its rubyisms, I have a code similar to this one :

```
def my_method objects
  temp = []

  objects.each do |o|
    temp <<  {
      :text => o.text,
      :title => o.title
    }
  end

  return temp
end
```

Could you help me to write this better ? Or show me some sources to learn this kind of rubyisms plz ? I'm already doing the ruby koans lessons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map):

```
def my_method objects
  objects.map { |e| {text: e.text, title: e.title} }
end
```

About the resources: I strongly recommend reading [Eloquent Ruby](http://eloquentruby.com/).

*Edit*

I used the Ruby 1.9.x hash syntax.

Comment: It may be good to indicate for beginners that the Hash syntax you are using is 1.9 only.

Comment: Ok, thx for the answer, for other readers, an answer about the difference between map and collect : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254732/ruby-difference-between-map-and-collect

Answer (score 1):

`objects.collect{|o| {:text=> o.text, :title => o.title} }`