# how to form an array from list of objects

Tags: ruby

I know little about ruby, my following implementation works, but I really feel the approach curbsome

```
@surfaces = []
Surface.all.each do |surface|
    @surfaces << surface.name
end
```

the purpose is to extract name value of each surface objects and form them into an array, can anyone tell me the smart way to do this? thanks

Comment: This is one of the most fundamental abstractions of functional programming (`map`): https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming#Blocks_as_higher_order_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#map`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) to turn one enumerable into another enumerable with a 1-to-1 mapping of elements. Combine with [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://apidock.com/rails/Symbol/to_proc) when the mapping involves simply invoking a single method on each element of the input enumerable.

Both of these are equivalent:

```
@surfaces = Surface.all.map(&:name)

@surfaces = Surface.all.map do |surface|
  surface.name
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Surface.all.collect(&:name)`.

EDIT: this is equivelent to doing something like this:

```
Surface.all.collect do |s|
  s.name
end
```

Comment: thank you, it works like magic. I looked up the method "collect {|item| block } → new_ary", so we pass in a block. But I don't understand the "&:name" part, can you help explain this? thanks

Comment: @ChrisChen take a look at my edit and also at meagar's answer

Answer (score 1):

FYI, collect and map alias to the same internal pattern in Ruby.

Here's the stackflow reference: [Difference between map and collect in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254732/ruby-difference-between-map-and-collect)