# aggregate values from specific key in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build an array of values that come from an array of hashes, at the moment my code looks like this:

```
ids = array_of_hashes.inject([]) do |result,instance|
    result << instance[:id]
    result
end
```

I just want to know if there's a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Your array of hashes is called `hash`?

Comment: no, just making it more obvious as to what it is, that isn't my code exactly just simplified to show what I currently have.

Comment: `array_of_hashes` or simply `hashes` would be obvious, `hash` is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy ways for it:

```
 1. ids = hash.collect{|h| h[:id]} 
 2. ids = hash.map{|h| h[:id]}
```

Now you would ask what is the difference in both? for explanation see [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254732/difference-between-map-and-collect-in-ruby)

Comment: I will tick this as correct simply because It possess both ways (even if the only difference is that one is an alias of the other) and has a source link for information, the other answer is still however correct.

Answer (score 4):

You could change it to look like:

```
ids = hash.map { |instance| instance[:id] }
```

Not necessarily more efficient, but easier to read and maintain!

Good luck!