# Rails 4 retrieve nested attributes for display in an index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, nested-attributes

Just looking to find out how to retrieve nested images for display on my front page. I have no problems with a standard model but have been unable to find how to bring has_many nested attribute through. All my nested Forms work fine just have neglected the front end.

eg. product has nested `product_images`. This doesn't look like a clever way of doing it as the last five images uploaded wont necessarily be related to the last five products added.

Could someone please share an example.

cheers

**app/controller/home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.last(5)
    @product_images = ProductImage.last(5)    
  end
end
```

**app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
  <% @products.each do |pd| %>
      <div><%= pd.product_name %>
       <% end %>
  <% @product_images.each do |pd| %>
        <%= image_tag (pd.product_image(:medium)) %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

app/controller/home_controller.rb

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @products = Product.last(5)
     @product_ids = @products.collect(:id)
     @product_images = ProductImage.where(:id => @product_ids).last(5)  
   end
 end
```

app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
 <% @products.each do |pd| %>
   <div><%= pd.product_name %>
 <% end %>
 <% @product_images.each do |pd| %>
   <%= image_tag (pd.product_image(:medium)) %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Sweet pluk didn't work but changed it to .map ` def index
    @products = Product.last(5)
    @product_ids = @products.map(&:id)
    @product_images = ProductImage.where(:product_id => @product_ids).last(5)
  end `

Comment: You can use `collect` also

Comment: Is there much difference between them?

Comment: There is no difference it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254732/difference-between-map-and-collect-in-ruby

Comment: Cheers tank you for the prompt answer.