# What is the difference between map and collect in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Example of each"
  x = [1,2,3]
  a = x.each{ |i|
    i+1
  }

  puts a.inspect
  puts x.inspect

puts "Example of map"
  b = x.map{ |i|
    i+1
  }

  puts b.inspect
  puts x.inspect

puts "Example of collect"
  c = x.collect{  |i|
    i+1
  }

  puts c.inspect
  puts x.inspect
```

**Output**

```
Example of each
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
Example of map
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
Example of collect
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
```

> Here we see each block returns the same value passed to it irrespective of the operation inside it. And the map and collect seems to be same. So basically what is the difference between map and collect?

Comment: There is a proper explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254732/difference-between-map-and-collect-in-ruby

Comment: Please follow the link : http://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/25/ruby-difference-between-collect-and-map/

From the explanation in the above link you will get to know that;
1. In Ruby difference between collect and map does not exist.
2. C level implementation of these methods shows that they both are same. 3. So, collect is an alias to Map.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely nothing, it's an alias.